# Proof by contradiction attempt involving the cartesian product of two non-empty sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I was wondering if the way I have tried to prove by contradiction the following claim is correct: 
 
 Given two nonempty sets $A$ and $B$, show that 
**if $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = A \times A$, then $A \subseteq B$**.

My proof by contradiction attempt:

Assume that $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = A \times A$, then $A \nsubseteq B$. 
Now suppose that $(x, y) \in(A \times B) \cup (B \times A)$.

$\Rightarrow$ ($x \in A$ and $y \in B$) or ($x \in B$ and $y\in A$)

 In both cases, we get a contradiction since both $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, or $y \in B$ and $y \in A$, which implies that sets $A$ and $B$ share at least one common element. Well, that is a contradiction since we assumed that $A \nsubseteq B$ (which means that set $A$ and $B$ share no common elemens).
$\square$

Is this sufficient to prove this claim by contradiction?

Comment: " since we assumed that A⊈B (which means that set A and B share no common elemens"  No.  $A$ and $B$ can share a common element without being subsets.  Consider $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$.  $1\in A$ and $1 \in B$ but $A\not\subset B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a proof by contradiction rather than a direct proof you must use the assumption $A\not \subset B$ which you didn't. $A$ and $B$ having a common element doesn't contradict $A$ not being a subset.  Consider $A = \{$ all even numbers $\}$ and $B = \{$ all perfect squares$\}$.  They share all even squares but neither is a subset of the other.

The negation of $A\subset B$ is that there is a $a\in A$ but $a \not \in B$.

If so note that $(a,a) \in A\times A$ so if $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)=A\times A$ then $(a,a)\in (A\times B)\cup (B\times A)$ so either $(a,a) \in A\times B$ and $a \in B$, a contradiction.  Of $(a,a)\in B\times A$ and $a \in B$, a contradiction.

Comment: I just want to clarify the last part. How is it the case that in both cases $a \in B$? Shouldn't in the first part ($(a, b) \in A \times B \Rightarrow a \in A$), and in the second ($(a, b) \in B \times A \Rightarrow a \in B$), and because it is an or statement, then it is sufficient that at least one of the statements would be true for the whole thing to become true, which is why we get that $a \in A$ and $a \in B$, thus, a contradiction?

Comment: $a\in A$ so $(a,a) \in A\times A = (A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$ so $(a,a)\in A\times B$ or $(a,a)\in B\times A$.  Either way, $a \in B$.

Answer (score 1):

No this proof doesn't make sense.

Why do you say that $x \in A $and $x \in B$ or $y\in B$ and $y \in A$?

And then you conclude that $A \subseteq B$ because A and B share an element which is a false assumption. Were you confusing this with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Isn't it the case that $A \subseteq B$ since both $x$ and $y$ are in $A$ and $B$? ($x \in A$ and $x \in B$) or ($y \in B$ and $y \in A$)?

Comment: Ok yes you are right that at least one of $x$ and $y$ is in both A and B. I'm still not convinced you have shown that $A \subseteq B$

Comment: Could you please give me a direction, perhaps?

Comment: If I were proving by contradiction I would start like this. Let $t \in A$ then we wish to show t must be in B contradicting our assumption. Then consider the element (t,t)... I don't want to finish it in case you don't want the answer just given to you.

Comment: @G Aker I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$A\subseteq B\overset{\mathrm{definition}}{\iff}\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B)$

$A\nsubseteq B\iff\exists x(x\in A\ \mathrm{and}\ x\notin B)$

So by assuming $A\nsubseteq B$, we get an element $x\in A$ that is not in $B$.

We could directly prove $A\subseteq B$. Let $x\in A$. Then $(x,x)\in A\times A$. And since $A\times A=(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$, $(x,x)\in(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$.